# Setting minimum date to date picked in previous datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two date pickers. A `startdate` and an `enddate`.

The way I have the code set up is that the second datepicker won't be initiated until the first one has been changed. The `enddate` datepicker is initialized with the current date on `startdate`. The only problem is that if you change the time on the first datepicker it doesn't refresh the `mindate` on `enddate`.

```
   $(function(){
   $( "#startdate" ).datepicker({ minDate: currentTime });

        //When the startdate changes change the mindate for the enddate picker
        $( "#startdate" ).change(function (){
             startTime = ($("#startdate").val());
            $("#enddate").datepicker({ minDate: startTime });

       });

       //$( "#enddate" ).datepicker({ minDate: currentTime });
  });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to use the `option` method as described in the documentation (http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#method-option) to update the `minDate` option of an already initialized widget:

```
$( "#startdate, #enddate" ).datepicker({ minDate: currentTime });

$('#startdate').change(function () {
    var startTime = ($("#startdate").val());
    $("#enddate").datepicker('option', 'minDate', startTime);
});
```

Notice I put a `var` statement in-front of the `startTime` variable so it will be declared in the local scope of the event handler. Also both Datepickers get initialized strait-off and then the `#enddate` widget gets an updated `minDate` option each time the `#startdate` element is changed.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/VP25m/

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Try using the refresh() function on datepicker:

```
$( "#startdate" ).change(function (){
    startTime = ($("#startdate").val());
    $("#enddate").datepicker({ minDate: startTime });
    $("#enddate").datepicker('refresh');

  });
```

OLD ANSWER BELOW:

You will probably want to set the end date datepicker to a variable so you can destroy and re-initialize it when the start date changes.

```
$( "#startdate" ).change(function (){
    startTime = ($("#startdate").val());
    if($("#enddate").datepicker("enabled")) {
          endDatePicker.datepicker( "destroy" );
    }
    var endDatePicker = $("#enddate").datepicker({ minDate: startTime });

  });
```

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#method-option -- All jQuery UI widgets have the ability to update options on-the-fly. There is generally an `option` method that can be used.

Answer (score 0):

Use `datepicker`'s `onSelect` event instead of `change` event of textbox. In this event you get the `selected` date as the first argument which you can use to set as `minDate` of enddate datapicker.

```
$( "#startdate" ).datepicker({ 
    minDate: currentTime,
    onSelect: function(date){

        //if the datepicker is not initialized
        $("#enddate").datepicker({ minDate: date });

        //if the datepicker is already initialized
        $("#enddate").datepicker("option", "minDate", date);
    } 
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/C4H8v/1/)**

Reference: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#event-onSelect